# Controller function not called after opening another tab in extjs mvc 4.0

Tags: extjs4

I've a function in controller of extjs4.0 MVC it called on button 
which is in view page but when I open another tab then this function not called 
on button

Kindly help me in this matter 
//------------- Code

```
init: function() {
       var controller = this;
       this.control({
           'leftPanel button[action=reset]': {
                click: this.resetForm
           },'leftPanel button[action=search]' : {
                click: this.searchForm
           }

       })
}
```

these 2 function will not call again if open another tab on my site

Kindly help me in this matter

Thanks

Comment: kinda difficult to give an answer without actually seeing code. Can you create a jsfiddle with your current code?

Comment: Also, do you get any kind of error message? Do your two functions "resetForm" or "searchForm" get called at all? (try adding "console.log('executing [function name]')" at the top of these functions to see if they are getting called)

Answer (score 0):

actually the fields are in view page like 
this

```
buttons: [{
                    text: 'Reset Filter',
                                        name :'btnReset',
                                        id:'btnReset',
                                        action:'reset'
                                    },{
                                         text: 'Perform Search',
                                         name:'btnSearch',
                                         id:'btnSearch',
                                         action:'search'

                                    }
                                   ]
```

you can see in config option defined 
the name of the function 'search , rest' which is defined in controller of the page (as I posted on my question). this function works 
properly when page load and if we not perform any action of this page where these function called but when I' opening a tab (by Using Ajax Request) after that the above function not called no error messages appear.

hopefully you can understand the problem

Comment: this is a part of question itself right? you can add this to the question as an UPDATE to the last.

Comment: Yes it part of question so that question is more easy to understand